# How to link to pistache in Eclipse C++

Tags: eclipse, gcc

I fail to link the [pistache](https://github.com/oktal/pistache/) library in Eclipse C++ on my Ubuntu machine.  I already make this reference:

1. Properties > C/C++ Build > Settings > Tool Settings
2. Under `GCC C++ Linker > Libraries > Library search path`
3. Under `GCC C++ Compiler > Includes > Include paths`
4. Add `/usr/local/include/pistache` to each

It throws a bunch of errors like this:

```
.... undefined reference to `Pistache::Ipv4::any()'
```

Why does this fail?  The autocomplete is able to see the reference when I try rewrite the whole line, but it still errors out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to let the linker use shared libraries and pass the -fpic option to the compiler:

a. [First step `-shared`, see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhaDm.png)

b. [Last Step Position Independent Code `-fPic`, see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnWVS.png)

## Update

Another way to solve this is:

a. Add support for pthread to the linker[image]

b.Add pistache to libraries in the linker[image]